# Can I merge pivot table data into parent object?

Tags: laravel

I have two models, `Category` and `Item`, that are connected via a pivot table.

The pivot table, `category_item`, has a column called `position`. On the category model, I am eager loading Items. I am wondering if it's possible to set the model up so that any time an Item is called, it automatically appends the `position` property to itself.

So for example, if I run in tinker something like `App\Models\Category::find(1)->items()->get()` and it returns that Category with its associated Items, I'd like each of those Items to also have the property of Position (which is found on the pivot table). Is this possible?

**Category.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    // automatically eager load items of a category
    protected $with = ['items'];

    // define relationships
    public function items(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Item')
            ->withPivot('position')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Item.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'category_id', 'quantity'
    ];

    // define relationships
    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category')
            ->withPivot('position')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be possible with Laravel's eager loading setup. Why don't you use `join` instead? If you want to keep laravel's relationships, you can use join along with belongsToMany, otherwise, just join the three table and specify the select list.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not familiar enough with Laravel. Could explain that a little more?

Comment: On second thought, since belongs to many is already a join, specifying a select list should also work i thibk. Ill post an answer for you to try out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

In your Category model:

```
public function items(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Item')
        ->select('items.*', 'category_item.position as position');
}
```

Now:

```
App\Models\Category::with('items')->find(1);
```

should give you the categories with items and position attached to items.

Try this out and let me know.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!